# How to sort a file using one of the columns as a group and another as a value in unix?

Tags: sorting, unix

Let's say I have this file, ordered using `sort -t $'\t' -k1,1 -k3,3gr`:

```
echo "A 6
A   5
A   4
B   7
B   2
C   10
C   9
C   8
" > my_file
```

Is there a way to order it like this?:

```
C   10
C   9
C   8
B   7
B   2
A   6
A   5
A   4
```

Basically, I want the group with largest value to appear first (`C`), followed by the group with the next biggest value (`B`), etc.

I know one way would be to create an auxiliary file like:

```
1,C
2,B
3,A
```

Then, I could merge it with the original file, but let's assume that we don't know the correct order beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, asking the question just helped me think of an answer. I add an extra column using awk with the largest value per group, and sort using that. Is there a simpler solution?

```
awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" '
FNR == NR{
    if ($2 > largest_by_group[$1]) {
        largest_by_group[$1] = $2
    }
    next
}
{
    print $1, $2, largest_by_group[$1]
}' my_file my_file | \
sort -t $'\t' -k3,3rg -k2,2rg |\
cut -f1,2
```

Comment: no, that sorts by letter first: `A:4 A:5 A:6 B:2 B:7 C:10 C:8 C:9`. Thanks